# Converting html to dict using pandas

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am trying to convert an HTML table into a dictionary using pandas.
I am extracting the HTML with beautiful soup and stared in the **tables** variable.

**This is what the DataFrame looks like:**

```
   Date        Value
0  2019          31
1  2018          11
2  2017          11
3  2016          10
4  2015          99
5  2014          98
```

**This is what I am doing**

```
 df = pd.read_html(str(tables), flavor='lxml')[0]
 final = df.to_dict(orient='index')
 return final
```

**And this is my result**

```
  "0": {
    "Date": "2019",
    "Value": "31"
  },
  "1": {
    "Date": "2018",
    "Value": "11"
  },
  "2": {
    "Date": "2017",
    "Value": "11"
  },
  "3": {
    "Date": "2016",
    "Value": "10"
  },
  "4": {
    "Date": "2015",
    "Value": "99"
  },
  "5": {
    "Date": "2014",
    "Value": "98"
  }
}
```

**I am looking for output like this:**

```
"Values" : [ 
                { "Date":  "2019",
                   "value" : "31"
                },
                { "Date":  "2018",
                   "value" : "11"
                },
                { "Date":  "2017",
                   "value" : "11"
                  },
                  { "Date":  "2016",
                    "value" : "10"
                  },
                  { "Date":  "2015",
                    "value" : "99"
                  },
                  { "Date":  "2014",
                    "value" : "98"
                  }
                ]
```

Answer (score 1):

isntead of :

```
df.to_dict(orient='index')
```

do:

```
df.to_dict(orient='record')
```

Comment: When i use the 'records', i get this error: `'list' object is not a mapping`
@adir

Comment: sorry but not enough information of the error provided

Answer (score 0):

the answer above is working but I think there is an unexpected error.
So, that should be `df.to_dict(orient='record')`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30565999)